# Lambda Expression Left Join

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda

I was reading this http://jcmartialarts.co.uk/CSharp/Using-Lambda-Expressions-To-LEFT-JOIN-Tables/43 but I cannot figure out how to do what I want.  I have this expression:

```
Dim myData = db.Tbl_Exercises.Where(Function(x) x.Exercise_Employee_ID)
```

My `Tbl_Exercise` model has an `Exercise_Type_ID`.  I want to use that ID to fetch the type of exercise description from my `Tbl_Exercise_Type` model which has an `ExType_Desc` property which is what I want to use in my application (in place of `Tbl_Exercise.Exercise_Type_ID`).

How can I do this?

**Edit:**

This is my model:

```
Public Class Tbl_Exercise

    <Key()> Public Property Exercise_ID() As Integer
    Public Property Exercise_Employee_ID() As Integer
    Public Property Exercise_Create_Date() As Date
    <ForeignKey("Tbl_Exercise_Type")>
    Public Property Exercise_Type_ID() As Integer
    Public Property Exercise_Duration() As Integer

    Public Overridable Property Tbl_Exercise_Type As Tbl_Exercise_Type

End Class

Public Class Tbl_Exercise_Type


    <Key()> Public Property ExType_ID() As Integer
    Public Property ExType_Desc() As String
    Public Property Exercise_Create_Date() As Date

    Public Overridable Property Tbl_Exercise() As ICollection(Of Tbl_Exercise)

End Class

Public Class ExerciseDbContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property Tbl_Exercises As DbSet(Of Tbl_Exercise)
    Public Property Tbl_Exercise_Types As DbSet(Of Tbl_Exercise_Type)

End Class
```

Thanks.

Comment: That article seems pretty clear. Can you be more specific about where you are having trouble?

Comment: Well I don't really know how to do it at all.  I don't understand the syntax given in the link I provided.  Plus, I'm using VB, not C#.

Comment: Ah... just realize that `o => o.OrderId` is equivalent to `Function (o) o.OrderId` and `(o, i) => new {o, i}` to `Function(o, i) New With {o, i}` [More thorough translation in a minute...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the translations below.

---

```cs
// C#
var OrderItems = Orders.GroupJoin(Items, o => o.OrderId, i => i.OrderId, (o, i) => new {o, i});
```

```vb
' VB.NET
Dim OrderItems = Orders.GroupJoin(Items, Function( o ) o.OrderId, Function ( i ) i.OrderId, Function( o, i ) New With {o, i})
```

---

```cs
// C#
var Item = OrderItems.SelectMany(oi => oi.i.DefaultIfEmpty(), (o,i) => new {o.o, i});
```

```vb
' VB.NET
Dim Item = OrderItems.SelectMany( Function( oi ) oi.i.DefaultIfEmpty(), Function ( o, i ) New With { o.o, i } )
```

---

```cs
// C#
var Qty = Item.Select(oi => oi.i.Qty);
```

```vb
' VB.NET
Dim Qty = Item.Select( Function( oi ) oi.i.Qty )
```

---

```cs
// C#
var Item = OrderItems.SelectMany(oi => oi.i.DefaultIfEmpty(), (o,i) => new {o.o.OrderDate, i.Qty});
```

```vb
' VB.NET
Dim Item = OrderItems.SelectMany( Function( oi ) oi.i.DefaultIfEmpty(), Function( o, i ) New With { o.o.OrderDate, i.Qty } )
```

---

**Complete Sample**

```
Class Order

    Private _orderId As Integer
    Public Property OrderId() As Integer
        Get
            Return _orderId
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _orderId = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Class Item

    Private _orderId As Integer
    Public Property OrderId() As Integer
        Get
            Return _orderId
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _orderId = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _qty As Integer
    Public Property Qty() As Integer
        Get
            Return _qty
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _qty = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim Orders = New Order() { _
            New Order With {.OrderId = 1}, _
            New Order With {.OrderId = 2}, _
            New Order With {.OrderId = 3} _
        }

        Dim Items = New Item() { _
            New Item With {.OrderId = 1, .Qty = 1}, _
            New Item With {.OrderId = 3, .Qty = 1}, _
            New Item With {.OrderId = 4, .Qty = 1} _
        }

        Dim OrderItems = Orders.GroupJoin(Items, Function(o) o.OrderId, Function(i) i.OrderId, Function(o, i) New With {o, i})
        Dim Item = OrderItems.SelectMany(Function(oi) oi.i.DefaultIfEmpty(), Function(o, i) New With {o.o, i})
        Dim Qty = Item.Select(Function(oi) oi.i.Qty)
        ' Dim Item = OrderItems.SelectMany(Function(oi) oi.i.DefaultIfEmpty(), Function(o, i) New With {o.o.OrderDate, i.Qty})
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think I am missing something.  I am trying to create my models (which I've just added to the question) but I am getting an error.  I don't know how to apply your answer to my scenario.  I am trying to just use `data.Add(New Object() {i.Tbl_Exercise_Type.ExType_Desc, i.Exercise_Duration})` (no left join) but I am getting an error on this line.

Comment: Like I said, you'll need to be more specific. What error are you getting?

Comment: The error just says, "`An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.`"  I'm not sure what the problem is but I assume it's in my model.

Comment: If you look at the InnerException property, you'll get more details. As far as `data.Add(...)` goes... there's nothing about that in your question.

Comment: The `data.Add()` part works, I am just trying to add the `Desc` in place of the `ID`.  So, the error says, "`{"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."}`."

Comment: I'd recommend purusing that error then. Sounds like this has nothing to do with left joining two tables.

Comment: This does have something to do with joining the tables being as I am trying to create the model in order to do so.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16977/discussion-between-cyborgx37-and-user1477388)

Comment: I figured it out finally; just had to keep solving the errors and it eventually worked :)  Thanks for your help.